# Принцип создания десктопного приложения на python + PyQt

Tags: python, gui, pyqt

Добрый день! Начал изучать Python + PyQt для создания GUI. Хочу написать просмоторщиик картинок. Где-то нашел идею, что лучше созжать несколько модулей: в одной описывать логику работы приложения, в другом описывать интерфейс (кнопочки, лайблы, слайдеры). Начал писать, сталкиваюсь с проблемой зависания интерфейса (прогресс-бар засыпает) в то время, пока внутрении процессы программы идут.
Подскажите азы, на чем строится создание GUI, или какие-нибудь туториалы.

Answer (score 1):

Интерфейс зависает скорее всего потому, что вы не используете многопоточность. Попробуйте выполнять модуль с GUI и основной модуль асинхронно, чтобы программа одновременно выполняла внутренние процессы и рисовала интерфейс независимо от этих процессов.

Пример создания второго потока:

```
import threading
import time

# бесконечный цикл, который никогда не прекращается
def some_func():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Test 1")

# Запуск функции some_func вторым потоком
task = threading.Thread(target=some_func)
task.start()

# этот цикл будет выполняться, хотя функция some_func тоже выполняется в этот момент
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Test 2")
```

Таким образом, прогресс-бар в вашей программе будет работать, хотя программа будет занята другой задачей

[Статья о многопоточности на Habrahabr](https://habrahabr.ru/post/149420/)

Comment: Спасибо! Стал использовать QThread

Answer (score 0):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QProgressBar
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QTimer
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def work(data):
    '''работа - каждые 0.5 сек уменьшать data'''
    while data:
        sleep(.5)
        data.pop()
        # обновить прогресс можно тут, тк dataLen это pyqtSignal, и можно обновлять gui из любого потока
        # минус в том что будет вызвано len(data)=100 обновлений прогресбара
        Wnd.dataLen.emit(len(data))

class Window(QMainWindow):
    '''прогресс длины списка data_'''
    dataLen = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, data):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.bar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.bar)

        self.data = data
        self.bar.setValue(len(data))
        # установить значение dataLen в bar
        self.dataLen.connect(self.bar.setValue)

        # если не использовать dataLen, то можно обновлять прогресбар, каждые x секунд по таймеру
    #     self.timer = QTimer()
    #     self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_bar)  # по истечению таймаута запустить self.update_bar
    #     self.update_bar()
    #
    # def update_bar(self):
    #     '''обновлять прогресбар каждые 3 сек'''
    #     data_len = len(self.data)
    #     self.bar.setValue(data_len)
    #     if data_len:
    #         self.timer.start(3000)  # установить таймер

if __name__ == '__main__':
    qa = QApplication([])

    data_ = list(range(100))
    Wnd = Window(data_)
    Thread(target=work, args=[data_]).start()  # работать в потоке

    Wnd.show()
    qa.exec_()
```